# How to add a JSeparator beside a JLabel in a Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

[image] How do I add all of these component in a `JPanel` by using `MigLayout` and achieve the rest of the conditions as described in the above picture?

Answer (score 6):

Using `MigLayout` you can simply add a `JSeparator` to the adjacent cell, giving it the `growx` property. For instance:

```
JLabel lblPersonal = new JLabel("Personal");
contentPane.add(lblPersonal, "cell 0 0");
contentPane.add(new JSeparator(), "cell 1 0,growx");
```

[image: A label with an adjacent separator]

Or, perhaps a nicer way, is to use a border on a panel, while giving the panel a title as such:

[image: A panel with a title and border]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class TitledPanel extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TitledPanel frame = new TitledPanel();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TitledPanel() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[grow]"));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY), "Personal"));
        contentPane.add(panel, "cell 0 0,grow");

        JLabel lblLabel = new JLabel("Label 1");
        panel.add(lblLabel);

        textField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        pack();
    }

}
```

Now, if you want to create a function that returns such panels when you pass a string parameter, you could extend a `JPanel` or create your own class that returns your custom-created `JPanel` with the given title label and separator.

Comment: +1 but `textField = new JTextField();` plus `textField.setColumns(10);` equals `textField = new JTextField(10);`

Comment: Not sure if this will meet the requirements of the OP, but you could also use `BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK), "Title")`

Comment: Your code is not the answer. Though you touch my question answer in your comments.

Comment: @user282606: What do you miss in his answer? I think he explained very well and even gave you a complete code example.

Comment: I think you have to provide a function that will take a string as JSeparator's title and the function will return a JPanel. Probably, you did not read the question that I asked

Comment: @user282606 You can easily make such said function yourself with the given information and from the hint I gave you in the last paragraph of my answer. Give it a try first and ask questions if you run into specific problems.